# Is it possible to use a USB stick as additional RAM, excluding the use of swap partitions?

Tags: firefox, swap, ram

This question is two-fold:

1. I have a crappy little netbook with just 4GB of RAM, I've been running Linux on there for a couple of years, with just 4GB of ram. It's functioned well under the circumstances, but freezes from time to time, usually because of Firefox. I've set up a swap partition today, and that's helped drastically, but I was wondering if there's any alternative way to set up a USB stick as external RAM or the equivalent to it?
2. Also, why did I not get asked about creating a swap partition when I originally installed this distro a couple of years ago? Seems like a strange question to have been left out of the installation process.

Finally, as a pre-emptive answer to the potential question of "why have you had this installed for a couple of years, but are only now setting up a swap partition?": I've simply not given it any thought.

Comment: Usage of usb flash memory for swap partition/file probably isn't a good idea. Swap contains segments from RAM and some third-party programs could store passwords and other unencrypted data. Second reason is that it would probably decrease system performance. If you need a swap space, please implement it as swapfile on local disk, most preferably encrypted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to use a USB stick as additional RAM, excluding the use of swap partitions?

No. From a system's point of view, memory is either *RAM* (the main memory, physically attached to the processor bus) or *swap*, the extended memory mapped to another device (usually disk). There is no other type of general memory.

**But** you can have multiple swap devices and assign a priority to each one, so that the faster ones are used first. Then your USB stick (slower than a local disk partition) would be used only as a last resort.

For example, create the swap space (preferably a partition) on the USB disk, run `mkswap` and the `swapon` with `--priority` (and change `/etc/fstab` to adjust the priority of the on-disk swap space).

You will then have the main memory, a high priority swap on disk and a lower priority swap on the USB stick.

The system might not be very responsive when starts to use the slower swap but it should keep on running.

`swapon --show` will let you know the usage, priority and type of each individual swap space.

Answer (score 3):

If your laptop is still using a spinning harddrive then you will get a massive improvement by replacing the disk with an SSD. (I'd recommend Crucial MX500 series.)

Once you've done that you can then add a swap file to your filesystem. This is likely to be significantly faster than using an external USB stick for swap.

Run these commands as root (`sudo -s`, for example):

```
# Create 4GiB swapspace file
dd bs=1M count=$((4*1024)) </dev/zero >/var/.swap_1

# Prepare the file as swapspace
chmod 600 /var/.swap_1
mkswap -L swap_1 /var/.swap_1

# Enable swapping
swapon /var/.swap_1

# Ensure it is used on reboot too
echo /var/.swap_1 none swap sw 0 0 >>/etc/fstab
```

Answer (score 1):

> if there's any alternative way to set up a USB stick as external RAM or the equivalent to it?

A USB drive is, when it comes to speed and access times, orders of magnitude slower than RAM in your machine. So, it plays (best case, probably) in the league of your internal hard drive.

RAM sits on the memory bus and can be accessed directly by processor instructions without further ado. Things on a USB drive need to be requested from the USB drive through a driver software, which translates requests to USB packets, and unpacks what the USB drive answers. So: no. Your USB drive cannot be an extension of your RAM.

You can make more SWAP space out of it (or you can store things you don't commonly need on it to have more space on your hard drive for SWAP). That's it.

> Also, why did I not get asked about creating a swap partition when I originally installed this distro a couple of years ago? Seems like a strange question to have been left out of the installation process.

You forgot to mention which distro you're using, so nobody can answer that.

However, for the last 1.5 decades all distros I encountered that had proper installers usually created a disk layout that includes SWAP space, by default. So, you might either be using niche, or you selected manual partitioning instead of using the defaults, and forgot to add a SWAP partition.

Answer (score 0):

If not a partition, just use a swap file. You can create one with commands:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/pendrive/swapfile count=4k bs=1M
mkswap /pendrive/swapfile
swapon /pendrive/swapfile
```

The problem here is that you can't remove the pendrive while the swapfile is in use. If you do that your system may crash. To turn off this swapfile use command:

```
swapoff /pendrive/swapfile
```

Comment: You also have to have `/pendrive` mounted before swap is added. If the OP wants this done automagically then a few tricks may need to be put in place instead of the normal fstab entries.